# php не верный вывод даты

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Код:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    echo date("m.d.Y");
    echo "<br>";
    echo strtotime("now");
    echo "<br>";
    echo date("m.d.Y",strtotime("now"));
```

> Почему дата не верная? php говорит 23 число, а на деле 24.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');`

Comment: Если нужны даты разных поясов, используйте `DateTime` http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php

Comment: Вот это я лоханулся..., спасибо Вам

Comment: Проверьте, всё исправили. Теперь должно быть 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ознакомьтесь с [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)**, как вам писали выше.

Если не указать временную зону, то оно определяется указанным по умолчанию в настройках [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/ru/configuration.file.php)